# What is ObjectPath parameter when initializing TaxonomyFieldValueCollection object in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy

I need to initialize an object of type `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection` 
and I need to pass `ClientRuntimeContext` and `objectPath` as two parameters.

Below is the constructor that I am using

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection taxonomyFieldValueCollection = 
new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(runtimeContextClient,objectPath );
```

I am unable to find out what exactly I need to pass as objectPath, What is the second parameter objectPath here?

Answer (score 1):

**ObjectPath** class Tracks how a client object is created in the `ClientRuntimeContext` class, so that the object can be re-created on the server. This class and its members are reserved for internal use and are *not intended to be used in your code.*

[MSDN ObjectPath class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.objectpath.aspx)

To Initializes a new instance of a **`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`** object use

```
= new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(
    context,
    fieldValue,
    creatingField)
```

**context**
Type: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext`

**fieldValue** 
Type: `System.String`
String to parse for value

**creatingField**
Type: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field`
Field that this value is bound to

[TaxonomyFieldValueCollection constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj165912.aspx)

Comment: I went through these MSDN articles but when it comes to implementation there are two constructors for TaxonomyFieldValueCollection. 1st one uses two arguments which are   ClientRuntimeContext and objectPath and the other one is the constructor you have mentioned above. I don't know the difference in these two constructors. There's no detailed description on these. I need two initialize a empty TaxonomyFieldValueCollection so i thought I should use the constructor with two arguments. Do you have any idea which one to use?

Comment: @SumuduP You should use the constructor mentioned in the answer , not sure what you want to do exactly, but if you want to pass an empty value to the TaxonomyFieldValueCollection , you can set the second parameter "fieldValue" as empty string or null